# Eclipse tells me that Long is not Comparable

Tags: java, types, parametric-polymorphism, generics

I am in a strange situation here, namely eclipse tells me that Long is "not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`". Any suggestions on what may be the cause? I'm pasting relevant code below

**abstract Pair:**

```
public abstract class Pair<T extends Comparable<? super T>, R> implements Comparable<Pair<T, R>>{

    private T tt;
    private R rr;

    public Pair(T t, R r){
        tt = t;
        rr = r;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return tt+ ": " +rr.toString();
    }
}
```

**concrete Pair:**

```
import utilities.Pair;

public class LogBookRecord<Long, String> extends Pair<Long, String>{

    LogBookRecord(Comparable t, Object r) {
        super(t, r);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

I tried changing abstract class header to:

```
public abstract class Pair<T extends Comparable<T>, R> implements Comparable<Pair<T, R>>
```

which did not help, and also to:

```
public abstract class Pair<T, R> implements Comparable<Pair<T, R>>
```

but then, in concrete class I get a notification which suggests that I should change type parameters to `<Comparable, Object>`.

Comment: What do you think `class LogBookRecord<Long, String>` does (the names between `<...>`)? Why do you think so?

Comment: It assigns types to generic parameters in abstract class?

Comment: You've declared your own generic types named `Long` and `String`.

Comment: If that's what that does, what does `extends Pair<Long, String>` do?

Comment: If I write `public class Generic<Integer> {}`, what does `Integer` refer to?

Comment: Use backticks for inline code. `\``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class LogBookRecord<Long, String> extends Pair<Long, String>{
                                ^                           ^
                                |                           |
      generic type variable declaration (new type names)    |
                                                  generic type arguments
```

That code is equivalent to

```
public class LogBookRecord<T, R> extends Pair<T, R>{
```

You've simply shadowed the names `Long` and `String` with your own type variable names.

Since `T` has no bounds, it is not necessarily `Comparable` and the compiler cannot validate them as type arguments to `Pair`.

What you want is

```
public class LogBookRecord extends Pair<Long, String>{
```

A class that is not generic, that provides concrete types as type arguments to the `Pair` superclass declaration.

[The Java Language Specification describes the class declaration syntax.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)

Comment: The errors disappeared, but I can't instantiate the object now.

Comment: @Suspended Please clarify. Which type can't you instantiate? What error is it giving you?

Comment: I can't instantiate LogBookRecord. I didn't try to run it but the constructor is complaining: "The constructor Pair<Long,String> (Long,Object) is undefined"

Comment: @Suspended Your `Pair` super-constructor is `public Pair(T t, R r){`. If `Long` is bound to `T` and `String` is bound to `R`, then your `LogBookRecord`'s super constructor is `public Pair (Long t, String r)`, but you are calling it with `super(t, r);` where `t` is of type `Comparable` and `r` is of type `Object`. You need to call your super constructor with the correct types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am following along the question and comments. Eclipse gave me tool tip for LogBookRecord's constructor which looks like:   `public LogBookRecord(Long t, String r) { super(t, r); }` Looks ok to me but I am still trying to test it out.

Comment: @Suspended could you please share your test code for this...here is mine: `LogBookRecord lbr = new LogBookRecord(2000L, "TestString"); System.out.println(lbr.compareTo(new LogBookRecord(2000L,"TestString")));`

Comment: Sure, I'll do it in a bit.